# python datetime formatting to 1/10 second

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to produce a date time string down to .1 second accuracy, with the form:

```
 201606041552015
```

I have the following:

```
    from datetime import datetime
    d = datetime.utcnow()
    format1 = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f"
    print (d.strftime(format1))
```

This produces:

```
20160604154133634000
```

Is there a way to set the format for 1/10 second only?

Comment: How about you remove the last two digits?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the date is `2016-06-04 23:59:59.999999`. If you would like the date to be rounded to `2016-06-05 00:00:00.0` instead of truncated to `2016-06-04 23:59:59.9`, then you could use:

```
import datetime as DT

now = DT.datetime(2016,6,4,23,59,59,999999)
def myformat(date, digits=1):
    timestamp = round((date - DT.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds(), 1)
    date = DT.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
    return str(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))[:-5]
print('{}\n{}'.format(now, myformat(now)))
# 2016-06-04 23:59:59.999999
# 2016-06-05 00:00:00.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the last 5 digits from your current formatting. I'd also add conventional placeholders, like so.

```
>>> d = datetime.utcnow()
>>> print (d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-5])
2016-06-04 16:00:53.9
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I was aware of string slicing, but wondered if there was a way to format it like I need.

Comment: @user61629 I think on most systems it's pretty reliable to just chop off the digits you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

To get a 1/10 of a second accuracy you need to remove the last 5 digits

```
d.strftime(format1)[:-5]
```